# Tempered distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $P$ be a vector whose components are polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and harmonic. it's true that exists a polynomial T that $\nabla T = P$?

I think this has something to be with Fourier transform, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the domain of your functions? What do you understand by "harmonics"? What does your question have to do with distributions? Are you familiar with the notion of $\operatorname{curl}$?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected and $\vec F=(F_1,\dots,f_n)\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field of class $C^1$, then $\vec F$ is a gradient if and only if
$$
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i},\quad1\le i,j\le n.\tag{*}
$$
If the $F_i$ are polynomials, then they are $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is simply connected. In order to be a gradient, they must satisfy (*). In that case, the potential function is in fact a polynomial.